# I am trying to get a if-elif condition running with OR operator

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

X=storing system name
if [ $X = "ABC" ];
echo " $X "
then
elif [ $X = "DEF" ] || [ $X = "GHI" ] || [ $X = "JKL" ]
echo " $X "
else
echo " $X "
fi
```

and this is not working.

```
./elif.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./elif.sh: line 8: `elif.....
```

Anyone, please help.
version Linux 3.0.101-107

regards

Comment: `then` *after* the `if` / `elif`, and if $X might contain spaces, use "$X" whereever you use it.

Comment: See: `help if` and take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

`then` has to be placed after condition statement.

Also as pointed by @ Charles Duffy

`$X` being unquoted means there are several undesired effects -- consider if `X='1 = 1 -o BCF'` -- then `[ $X = "ABC" ]` becomes `[ 1 = 1 -o BCF = ABC ]`, which returns true even though the strings the OP intends to compare aren't equal at all. This wouldn't happen if it were `[ "$X" = ABC ]`.

```
#!/bin/bash

X=storing system name
if [ "$X" = "ABC" ];then
  echo " $X "
elif [ "$X" = "DEF" ] || [ "$X" = "GHI" ] || [ "$X" = "JKL" ];then
  echo " $X "
else
  echo " $X "
fi
```

Comment: Demonstrating readable indentation would help

Comment: Also, `$X` being unquoted means there are several undesired effects -- consider if `X='1 = 1 -o BCF'` -- then `[ $X = "ABC" ]` becomes `[ 1 = 1 -o BCF = ABC ]`, which returns true even though the strings the OP intends to compare aren't equal at all. This wouldn't happen if it were `[ "$X" = ABC ]`.

Comment: I have made the changes, thanks for pointing out @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of mistake in your shell script. First in-order to evaluate the variable you need to add your content in quotes. And the usage of then is not correct.

**Syntax of bash if condition**

```
if [ condition ]; then
    <commands>
elif [ condition ]; then
     <commands>
else
     <commands>
fi
```

---

I modified your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

X="storing system name"
if [ "$X" = "ABC" ]; then
    echo " $X "
elif [ "$X" = "DEF" ] || [ "$X" = "GHI" ] || [ "$X" = "JKL" ]; then
    echo " $X "
else
    echo " $X "
fi
```

Comment: This is still wrong. It needs to be `[ "$X" = "ABC" ]` -- each operand needs to parse as a separate shell word. (And actually, there's no reason to quote the constant string `ABC` at all).

Comment: Keep in mind that quoting is evaluated character-by-character -- so `"$X = "` says that the expansion of `$X` is performed quoted, and the `=` with its surrounding spaces are thus added into the same literal; then you have `ABC` unquoted, and `""` is just opening and closing a new pair of quotes, thus cancelling each other out. This means the net effect is exactly identical to `if [ "$X = ABC" ]`, which is testing whether the string created by that expansion is empty or not. It will **never** be empty, no matter what the value of `X` is, so the condition will thus *always* be true.

Comment: @charles, i thought string constant need quotes. I ll correct my answer. Thanks for pointing out.